# Thread unsafe object inside thread safe method

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm using this:

```
@Override
public synchronized void catchException(String logTag, Exception e) {

    StringBuilder trace = new StringBuilder(e.toString() + "\n");

    for (StackTraceElement el : e.getStackTrace()) {
        trace.append("\t\t at " + el.toString() + "\n");
    }

    write(logTag, trace.toString(), EXCEPTION);
}
```

Since `StringBuilder` is not thread safe, is it safe for it to use inside a thread safe, `synchronized` method? My guess is that, it is, because the Object itself is local and thread safe inside the method.

Comment: Your method is threadsafe because it is synchronized and because variable is local, there is no way other threads can access that local variable other than current thread executing that method.

Comment: "Thread-safe" means that the object can be safely used by _two or more_ threads at the same time.  There's no possible way for the StringBuilder to be used by more than one thread in your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is safe to use `StringBuilder` since it local for the method and does not escape to any other thread.